# Does having Root Motion applied prevent moving a transform position relative to world coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, hololens

I have "GameObject 0" (GO0) with an animation controller that used parameters to transform states and is used as a wrapper for "GameObject 1"(GO1). "GameObject 1" has an animation controller that has Root Motion applied. Within GO1 there are 3 game objects whos animation is in the same animation clip as GO1.

This allows me to place GO1 in world coordinates and animate GO1's children in local coordinates to maintain relative positioning.

However, I am wish to move one of the children of GO1 to a world coordinate that is not relative to GO1. I have used script and Vector3.Lerp / Vector3.MoveTowards functions, but they are not working as expected. Is the Root Motion interfering with the Lerps?

Comment: yes, but you should be able to move children relative to the animated parent

Answer (score 0):

I have change the script to add a  *new parent* to the child object and animating the new parent. This seems to work but the rotation of the new parent is causing a new issue.